# How to run a .vbs file in Robotframework by calling a Python function?

Tags: python-3.x, vbscript, robotframework

I am trying to create a custom Keyword in Robotframework, which should run a .vbs file, and then add that keyowrd to the Test Teardown so that the .vbs file should run after each test case is completed. But when I run the code I get an error "Keyword 'Common.CallVBS' expected 0 arguments, got 1". I am new to Python and coding and not able to figure it out.

## Below is the code I have in .py file under "CustomLibraries" directory -

```
Import subprocess

def call_vbs(scriptpath):
    try:
        subprocess.call('cscript.exe ' + scriptpath)
        return "PASS"
    except:
        return "FAIL"
```

## Below is the "CommonCommands.robot" file where I have the custom keyword at the end "CallVBS"-

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  It holds common functionalities related to all the Test Cases
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  ../CustomLibraries/Calling_VBS.py

*** Variables ***
${scriptpath}  ${EXECDIR}\\CustomLibraries\\saving.vbs

*** Keywords ***
CallVBS
    ${success}  call_vbs  ${scriptpath}
    Run Keyword If  "${success}"=="FAIL"  FAIL  Not able to launch VBS file
    log  ${scriptpath}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not linked with the `call_vbs` keyword from the library, but with the `CallVBS` keyword inside the Robot file.

When calling the `CallVBS` keyword you shouldn't add any parameters. Or, add an arugments line to the CallVBS keyword like this:

```
CallVBS
    [Arguments]    ${argument1}
    ${success}  call_vbs  ${scriptpath}
    Run Keyword If  "${success}"=="FAIL"  FAIL  Not able to launch VBS file
    log  ${scriptpath}
```

Also, I would suggest you wrap the python keywords in a class, like this:

```
Import subprocess

class Custom(object):
    def call_vbs(self, scriptpath):
        try:
           subprocess.call('cscript.exe ' + scriptpath)
           return "PASS"
        except:
           return "FAIL"
```